# How to filter a grouped DataFrame by maximum values in each group using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pandas-groupby

*I hope you are doing well in the current situation*

I've the following dataFrame as an input:

```
df_0 = pd.DataFrame({"year" : [1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1962, 1962, 1962,],
                     "genre": ['Action', 'Crime', 'Action', 'Drama', 'Thriller', 'Thriller', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Drama', 'Thriller'],
                     "popularity": [1.99, 0.53, 1.81, 0.23, 3.86, 3.94, 0.21, 4.30, 5.60, 0.09] })
```

**figure 0:**

```
        year    genre   popularity
0       1960    Action    1.99
1       1960    Crime     0.53
2       1960    Action    1.81
3       1960    Drama     0.23
4       1961    Thriller  3.86
5       1961    Thriller  3.94
6       1961    Crime     0.21
7       1962    Drama     4.30
8       1962    Drama     5.60
9       1962    Thriller  0.09
```

I've created a new dataFrame `df_1` by grouping by values like this:

```
df_1 = df_0.groupby(['year','genre']).popularity.agg(['mean','max'])
```

**figure 1:**

```
                    mean    max
year    genre       
1960    Action      1.90    1.99
        Crime       0.53    0.53
        Drama       0.23    0.23
1961    Crime       0.21    0.21
        Thriller    3.90    3.94
1962    Drama       4.95    5.60
        Thriller    0.09    0.09
```

As a result, we've got a similar dataFrame as the following:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"year" : [1960, 1960, 1960, 1961, 1961, 1962, 1962,],
                     "genre": ['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Crime', 'Thriller', 'Drama', 'Thriller'],
                     "mean ": [1.90, 0.53, 0.23, 0.21, 3.90, 4.95, 0.09],
                     "max"  : [1.99, 0.53, 0.23, 0.21, 3.94, 5.60, 0.09] }).set_index("year")
```

And I'm struggling with the next steps.
I would like to create the following dataFrame `df_2` from `df_1` *(.groupby())* using only pandas functions *(and no numpy or at the minimum)*:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({"year" : [1960, 1961, 1962],
                     "genre": ['Action', 'Thriller', 'Drama'],
                     "mean ": [1.90, 3.90, 4.95],
                     "max"  : [1.99, 3.94, 5.60] }).set_index("year")
```

**figure 2:**

```
        genre     mean  max
year            
1960    Action    1.90  1.99
1961    Thriller  3.90  3.94
1962    Drama     4.95  5.60
```

**This dataFrame `df_2` collects the maximum values of each group.**

Any tips?
Thank you for your support.

*Stay safe*

Comment: Can you explain `df_2`?  The numbers don't seem to com from `df_1`.

Comment: The dataFrame df_2 collects the maximum values of each group.

Comment: What do you mean by *each group*? Where's that `1.87` coming from, I don't see it in `df_1`.

Comment: I've updated the description above with 3 figures. If we look at the figure 1, there are 3 groups: the group 1960 with 3 samples,  the 1961 with 2 samples, the group 1962 with 2 samples. Which sample of each group has the maximum values? For example, in the group 1960, how to query or filter the DT to find out which sample has the maximum MEAN or the maximum MAX? And repeat for each group until to get a filtered DT with all expected results.

Comment: `1.87` was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The idmax() function gets the job done:

```
df_1 = df_0.loc[df_0.groupby('year').popularity.idxmax()].set_index("release_year")
```

Thx to Phil and Corrodo for their supports.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

# querying the results you want from df_1 and reseting index to turn
# year and genre into columns
df_2 = df_1.query('year in [1960, 1961] and genre in ["Action", "Thriller"]').reset_index()
```

The result will look like this:

```py
   year     genre  mean   max
0  1960    Action   1.9  1.99
1  1961  Thriller   3.9  3.94
```

### Update

According to your updated question try the following:

```py
# this will look for the entry with the biggest value for 'max'
# and extract its indices
indices = df_1.groupby('year')['max'].nlargest(1).index.get_level_values(1)

df_2 = df_1.loc[indices].set_index('year')
```

This will result in the result you stated in **figure 2**

Comment: Thank you for your message.

Comment: When I try the following lines:
YEARS  = sorted(list(set(df_1.index.to_list())))
GENRES = sorted(list(set(df_1.genre.to_list())))
df_1.query('year in YEARS and genre in GENRES').reset_index()

I get a error message saying "UndefinedVariableError: name 'YEARS' is not defined".

Comment: Prefix your variables in the query string with `@` according to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

Comment: I realize your code do not answer the question. It filters the DT presupposing the answer, knowing in advance the sample with the maximum value. The orignal DT has several thousands of samples. Meaning, the filtering or the query needs to specify the fact we are interested only on the maximum value of each group of sample (grouped by year). Am I right? Thx you for trying Any way.